# Python Import a List from Another File

Tags: python, arrays, list, function

(CHECK UPDATE BELOW)

I'm having trouble with importing a list from another file.
I'm still learning how to call/pass variables in functions.

I have something very similar to this example,

```
#file1
list_one = [] #global
list_two = [] #global

def function_list_one():
# code
    return list_one

def function_list_two(list_one, list_two):
# code
    return list_two

def both_lists(list_one, list_two):
# code
    return new_list
    # return new_list outputs a JSON list

both_lists(list_one, list_two) # this is used to call it from main
```

So far, if I print this new list it works from within this file. It prints what I want. However, if I try to do the next few things then it just prints an empty list. The last time from file1 is for the main file where I call that function using those parameters.

```
#file2
from file1 import both_lists, list_one, list_two

new_list = both_lists(list_one, list_two)
new_list2 = list_two
print(new_list)
# outputs = []
prin(new_list2)
#outputs = []

# Expected output should be the results from new_list from file1, which 
# would be a JSON type list.
```

This is where nothing happens. If I try both methods, they return an empty list. I understand I have a global variable for both list_one and list_two. What I don't understand is why it returns an empty list when I have used this same method in another program I made. Basically, I want to use the "return new_list" in fil2 in order to proceed with the rest of the program.

Update:
I found the solution. Somehow file2 when I import the `new_lists` it didn't like it. So, instead I just `import both_lists(function_list_one(), function_list_two())`

Thank you all for your time!

Comment: I think, you're going to need to give more info. How are the lists populated, and how is `new_list` generated?

Comment: It's not helpful to say "I tried this other thing and it didn't work", because we have no idea _what_ you tried.  Show us _the actual code_ you tried, show us the _output_ you got, and _explain_ how it wasn't what you wanted.

Comment: I did show the actual code I tried that didn't work. It's in file2

Comment: "didn't work" is not helpful.  Show us _what that code did_, and explain _what you wanted instead_.

Comment: I added some more information.

Comment: Perhaps a typo, but file1 has a function named `both_lists`, and file2 imports `both_list` (without the "s" on the end).

Comment: That is my mistake from typing it here. I do have the correct name on my program.

Comment: I don't see anything obvious that would make this happen.  There must be some code inside `both_lists()` that is doing it.  If you posted the full code, maybe we can help further.

Comment: I understand what you mean. The problem is that file1 works just fine. If I print `new_list` above there `return new_list` it prints out the right result. Now, if I want to do that from the other file, it doesn't (prints out an empty list).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you're importing the lists as defined, not as they are built by your `function_list_*` functions.

When you import `list_one` and `list_two`, you are importing them as empty lists, as file 1 has them:

```
list_one = [] #global
list_two = [] #global
```

If `both_lists()` is just appending them, then what you're getting for `new_list` in file 2 is just both of those empty lists appended together, or just another empty list.

I think what you're after is the result of appending `function_list_one(list_one)` and `function_list_two(list_two)`. There's a number of ways you could accomplish that, but perhaps the simplest is to redefine `both_lists()` to do something like this:

```
def both_lists(list_one, list_two):
    # Code
    return function_list_one(list_one) + function_list_two(list_two)
```

Then, when you import `both_lists`, you also import the functionality defined for your list-building functions.

To sum up:

As written, your imports are importing these items:

- `list_one = []`
- `list_two = []`
- `both_lists`, which I'm assuming just appends `list_one` and `list_two`

The code in `function_list_one()` and `function_list_two()` won't execute unless you import and call those functions or include their functionality in something that you do import - and then call that.

My suggestion above is just one way around this, and that's assuming I read your code correctly! Hope this helps, though. :^)

Comment: In regards to your answer. That is basically what I did with `return new_lists`. I did some stuff inside the `both_list()` function that basically take both `list_one` and `list_two` make some comparing and deletes specific keys and append them into `new_list`. As I commented above, if I print `new_lists` inside file1, it returns the answer I'm looking for. So, my approach in file2 is wrong and I don't know why since I used that exact method on another program and it worked. Except that in that program I used files instead of lists/array